# Having troubles inserting multiple records at once without using for loop in sql server database using node.js

Tags: javascript, mysql, sql, node.js

Hello guys I'm new in using mysql library in node js and I'm interested in possibility of inserting multiple rows at once in database. I've made a simple code which captures user registration id from database table and uses indexes of roles which that user has selected. And now I want to add user and role id into Role_User table which has user_id and role_id respectively.

Let's say I wanna do this 3 times without using loop:

```
Insert Into User_role VALUES (1,20);

Insert Into User_role VALUES (2,20);

Insert Into User_role VALUES (3,20);
```

, where numbers 1,2,3 of the first columns are role indexes.

```
Error I'm getting is RequestError: Incorrect syntax near '?'.
```

How can I make this query work?

```
if(req.body.roles){
                var sqlQuery = `SELECT ID from Test_user Where email = @email`;
                var indexiRola = findPositions(db.ROLES, req.body.roles);
                request.input('role', db.sql.NChar, req.body.roles);
                request.query(sqlQuery).then(
                    id => {
                        let ids = Array(req.body.roles.length).fill(id.recordset[0].ID);
                        console.log(ids); // [20, 20, 20]
                        let roleUsers = createSeperateLists(indexiRola, ids);
                        console.log(roleUsers); // [ [ 1, 20], [ 2, 20], [ 3, 20] ]
                        var insertQuery = `INSERT INTO Role_User ("role_ID", "user_id") VALUES ?`;
                        request.query(insertQuery, [roleUsers], function(err, result){
                            if(err) throw err;
                            console.log("Successfull insertion");
                        });
                    })
                }
```

Comment: insert into testuser (username, password) 
 VALUES ('user1', 1234),
    ('user2', 1234),
    ('user3', 1234);
This is the sql query for inserting multiple rows together, it means you need to insert array type data for values

Answer (score 0):

Check if it helps, please. I cannot check it running, of course.

It's not complete, on the contrary! `request.query` is async, and that code has to be revised.

At least, this code, as I hope, does not break into `RequestError: Incorrect syntax near '?'.`

Please:

- check if the revision works for one input
- whenever you get the complete solution, share it with us

```
    if (req.body.roles) {
        var sqlQuery = `SELECT ID from Test_user Where email = @email`;
        var indexiRola = findPositions(db.ROLES, req.body.roles);
        request.input('role', db.sql.NChar, req.body.roles);
        request.query(sqlQuery).then(
            id => {
                let ids = Array(req.body.roles.length).fill(id.recordset[0].ID);
                console.log(ids); // [20, 20, 20]
                let roleUsers = createSeperateLists(indexiRola, ids);
                console.log(roleUsers); // [ [ 1, 20], [ 2, 20], [ 3, 20] ]
                // I removed the double quotes from the names and,
                // VALUES (?, ?) - this is the right syntax for SQL
                const insertQuery = 'INSERT INTO Role_User (role_ID, user_id) VALUES (?, ?)';
                // Then, forEach roleUsers
                // By the way, [roleUsers] yields an array of arrays of arrays, not cool
                roleUsers.forEach(
                    roleUser => {
                        request.query(
                            insertQuery,
                            roleUser,
                            // Oh! Shoot!!! This is async.
                            // Man, you will have to deal with it.
                            // Please, share with us the final solution!
                            function(err, result) {
                                if (err) throw err;
                                console.log("Successfull insertion");
                            }
                        );
                    }
                );
            })
    }
```

Comment: still getting the following error : UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: RequestError: Incorrect syntax near '?'.